# Conversion error in a method that returns a lambda expression

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, std-function

This code works without problem:

```
#include "iostream"
#include  "functional"
std::function<double (double)> retFun(double* a) {
     return [a](double x) { return x+*a; };
 }

 int main(){

 double*e = new double(3);
 std::cout << retFun(e)(3) << std::endl;}
```

but if I declare `retFun` in an object:

.h

```
class InternalVariables : public Page
{
private:
    std::function<double ()> retFun(double* a);
};
```

.cpp

```
std::function<double ()> InternalVariables::retFun(double *a)
{
    return [a](double b){ return b+ *a;};
}
```

I obtain the following error

> error: could not convert ‘InternalVariables::retFun(double*)::__lambda44{a}’ from ‘InternalVariables::retFun(double*)::__lambda44’ to ‘std::function’
>        return [a](double b){ return b+ *a;};

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::function<double ()>` means that your wrapped function object will take no arguments and return a `double`. `[a](double b){ return b+ *a;}` is a lambda that takes a `double` and returns a `double`. The two signatures are mismatched.

You should change your return type to `std::function<double (double)>`.

---

Also:

- Standard Library headers should be included with `<...>`. Example: `<iostream>`.
- There's no need to allocate a `double` on the heap to get a pointer to it. Just use `&` on a `double` on the stack. Allocations in C++11 should be always done through *smart pointers*, do not use `new`/`delete`.
- You might want to simply return `auto` instead of `std::function`. The latter is a type-erased wrapper over any function object. Lambdas have their own anonymous type.